# Shortcut for quick directory navigation in the bash shell

Tags: linux, terminal, directory

I'm looking for shortcuts that would help me to navigate directories quickly and efficiently.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague but in Bash and zsh you can define an alias like this: `alias xyz='cd /dir/I/always/work/on/'`

Comment: Sorry! I should've elaborated on my question. Right, aliases will solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: What operating system? And What shell?

Comment: Pop OS 19.10. Bash shell.

Comment: You can also just run new terminals from another terminal that's already in the directory you want it to open in, terminals open in the current directory of the parent process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might add a short alias to your shell's login script file (e.g. `~/.bashrc` if you are using the common default `bash` shell):

```
alias w='cd /full/path/to/the/dir/I/always/work/on`
```

When this alias is in effect, you can just type `w` and press Enter in the command prompt to switch into the pre-determined directory.

Setting up a GUI shortcut to open a terminal in a specific directory automatically can be tricky, depending on whether or not your Linux distribution starts individual terminal windows as equivalent to independent login sessions or not. If it does, the terminal emulator may not be able to override the directory the new login session starts in.

If the new terminal window is started as a sub-shell of the main GUI session, then it might be possible if a) your shell startup scripts (both system-wide and your personal one) don't include any commands like `cd $HOME` and b) your terminal emulator allows specifying a directory to start in. In the best case, it might be as simple as making a copy of the [`.desktop` file](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html) that is used to start your terminal window normally, and adding a line to the `[Desktop Entry]` section of the copy:

```
Path=/full/path/to/the/dir/I/always/work/on
```

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "easily `cd` to that directory from anywhere", you can try [CDPATH](https://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~razvan/blog/some-bash-tricks-cdpath-and-inputrc/).  This is a shell variable that contains a colon separated paths of directories under which to look for directories to `cd` into.  For example, if the directory you want to have quick access to is `/a/b/c/interesting_dir`, then you'd put in `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
CDPATH=.:/a/b/c
```

Then no matter what your current working directory can do `cd int<TAB>` to do tab completion on `interesting_dir`, then when you hit `ENTER` you'll wind up in `/a/b/c/interesting_dir`

Comment: Thank you for reaching out! I appreciate the help.